# Laravel 5 redirect loop error

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-5, infinite-loop, middleware

I trying to make a login and admin script, the problem is that I have a redirect loop I dont know why.

I want the login users and can be in the `/` path not `/home`.

If change `return new RedirectResponse(url('/'));` to `return new RedirectResponse(url('/anotherpage'));` it works but I want to be `/`

**Routes:**

```
    Route::get('/', [
        'as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index'
    ]);


    // Tutorials Routes

    Route::get('/tutorials', 'HomeController@tutorials');
    Route::get('/tutorials/{category?}', 'HomeController@tutorialsCategory');
    Route::get('/tutorials/{category?}/{lesson?}', 'HomeController@tutorialsLesson');

    // Courses and Series Routes

    Route::get('/courses-and-series', 'HomeController@coursesandseries');

    // Admin Routes

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware'],                 function()
    {
        Route::get('/admin', function()
        {
            return 'Is admin';
        });
    });

    Route::controllers([
        'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
        'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
    ]);
```

**Admin middleware:**

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->type != 'Admin')
        {
            return abort(404);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

**RedirectIfAuthenticated:**

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->auth->check())
        {
            return new RedirectResponse(url('/'));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

**Home Controller:**

```
class HomeController extends Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }

    public function tutorials()
    {
        return view('pages.tutorials');
    }

    public function tutorialsCategory()
    {
        return view('pages.tutorials');
    }

    public function tutorialsLesson()
    {
        return view('pages.single');
    }

    public function coursesandseries()
    {
        return view('pages.coursesandseries');
    }

    public function single()
    {
        return view('pages.single');
    }
}
```

Comment: try returning this `return new RedirectResponse(route('home'));`

Comment: Its not working ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: are these the only routes you have? do you have a middleware in a controller construct? Did you attach a middleware to HomeController? May i see the code for HomeController. The issue might be from it

Comment: I add the homecontroller in the post, i only create the AdminController. Thanks

Comment: remove $this->middleware('guest');

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are having these redirection loops because all the methods in HomeController are protected by Guest Middleware.

Since you wish to redirect authenticated users to HomeController@index

Remove `$this->middleware('guest');` from HomeController

or

Modify the Guest Middleware to ignore index method

`$this->middleware('guest', ['only' => ['tutorials','tutorialsCategory']])`

List other methods you wish to protect with Guest Middleware excluding Index method