# Redirect to Dashboard page by IP Address with Auth

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, middleware

I want to auto redirect to dashboard page by pass login page if client ip address are match ip address 192.168.1.154. But in my Dashboard page i already put session by Auth

My Middleware in kernel:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,           
        'ipcheck' => \App\Http\Middleware\IpMiddleware::class,
    ];
```

My IpMiddleware code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class IpMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // $ip = \Request::ip();
        if ($request->ip() == "192.168.1.154") {               
            return redirect('home');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

My Route login:

```
Route::get('/', ['middleware' => ['ipcheck'], function () {
    return view('auth.login');
}]);
```

My Route home:

```
Route::get('home', function () {

    if (Auth::guest()) {
        return back()->withInput();
    } else (Auth::user()->role_id == 1) {

        return view('dashboard');
    } 

});
```

i got an error :

```
This webpage has a redirect loop

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

What can i do now?

Comment: Looks like middleware issue I think

Comment: Look at this question might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125235/laravel-5-redirect-loop-error

Comment: @SagarGautam How can we use return eturn redirect('/home')->with(Auth::user()->role_id=1);

Comment: @SagarGautam : I think problem because it's redirect without Auth

Comment: You want to redirect to two different dashboard based on user type ?

Comment: @SagarGautam: Only one dashboard but i want to redirect with Auth

Comment: Little bit strange problem here

Comment: One way might be you need to write the functions in the controller instead of route file and protect route with auth middleware

Comment: First change this `return redirect('homne');` to `return redirect('home');`

Comment: After that write your code in a separate controller

Comment: @SagarGautam public function autologin()
    {
        $ip = \Request::ip();
        if ($ip == '192.168.1.154') {
            return redirect('home');
        }
        else{
            return view('auth.login');
        }
    }

Comment: @SagarGautam and my route Route::get('/','AutologinController@autologin');

Comment: No, I am taking code in route file in last code above, Middleware should n't be changed

Comment: @SagarGautam: Can u create the answer because so difficult to read by comment

Comment: share your dashboard code where you `already put session by Auth` ?

Comment: **Comments are not for extended discussion, folks!** I've deleted a bunch of noisy comments. If you want to add more information to the question, [edit] it. If you want to answer it, then post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make auto login/session in you `middleware` not in `dashboard`

Let say if you want autologin for id `1` then it should be like this

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
// $ip = \Request::ip();
    if ($request->ip() == "192.168.1.154") {               
        $user_id = 1;//
        Auth::loginUsingId($user_id);
        return redirect('home');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

In your `home` route your check `Auth` which true for guest not for logged in user so it again redirect to `auth.login` because `auth.login` has middleware to redirect to `home` then `home` check for `guest` or `Auth` ..... and its make cicle and you got error

> This webpage has a redirect loop
>
> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS